# Перевод OpenDialog.FileName в строку

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, база-данных, sqlite

В связи с вопросом [Открытие sqlite базы в Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166943/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-sqlite-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B2-delphi) я начал рассматривать типы входных параметров.
Я изменил код

```
procedure TMainWindow.OpenDialog1Close(Sender: TObject);
begin
  partofconnectstring:=ExtractFilePath(String(OpenDialog1.FileName))+ExtractFileName(String(OpenDialog1.FileName));
  Label1.Caption:=partofconnectstring;
  Edit1.Text:=partofconnectstring;
  ConnectToDatabase(partofconnectstring, SQLConnection1);
  CreateObjs(SQLConnection1, DBSchema);
  //IBDatabase1.DatabaseName:='127.0.0.1:'+ChangeFileExt(OpenDialog1.FileName, '.fdb');
end;
```

так как в процедуре `ConnectToDatabase` входной параметр `string`, то возникает вопрос как преобразовать `OpenDialog1.FileName` в `string`, так как выше приведенный код не работает. При отладке `partofconnectstring` отображалась как пустая строка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память, тоOpenDialog1.FileName уже возвращает string, и никаких преобразований делать не надо.

только советую делать по-другому. сделайте это все в отдельной процедуре (например MyProc), и вызывайте ее так:

```
procedure TForm1.MyProc(FileName: string);
begin

partofconnectstring:=ExtractFilePath(FileName)+ExtractFileName(FileName);
  Label1.Caption:=partofconnectstring;
  Edit1.Text:=partofconnectstring;
  ConnectToDatabase(partofconnectstring, SQLConnection1);
  CreateObjs(SQLConnection1, DBSchema);
  //IBDatabase1.DatabaseName:='127.0.0.1:'+ChangeFileExt(FileName, '.fdb');
end;

procedure TForm1.AnotherProc;
begin
 if OpenDialog1.Execute() then
   if FileExists(OpenDialog1.FileName) then
     MyProc(OpenDialog1.FileName);  
end;
```

А лучше сделать не процедуру, а функцию. И обрабатывать после нее ошибки подключения к базе